# How to get the "Allow Notifications" status on "Screen Sharing" mode in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, sharing

In iOS 15 in Settings -> Notifications -> Screen Sharing we have a new switch "Allow Notifications". Is it possible to get its status from my app? If yes, how?